# Diode in parallel with AC solenoid valve

Tags: diodes, ac, flyback, solenoid, solenoid-valve

I have a circuit I'm trying to design to fire both 120VAC and 24VDC solenoid valves. We have relays that work on 12vdc for the coil, and can switch AC or DC. the valves are normally around 30W. I would like to put a diode in parallel with the valve solenoid which I know will help with DC flyback. But my question is when I use the same circuit for an AC valve, will the diode provided any use or could it potentially cause problems? If it simply doesn't hurt anything In AC mode and helps in DC then I'm fine with that. Then for AC I can look into other more appropriate flyback solutions.

Comment: I also have been reading that a bidirectional TSV may be useful here but I have no experience with these.

Comment: Would you also know, in general, whether the DC was hooked up the right way around?

Comment: As I understand it, solenoids are nonbiased. So it shouldn't matter? The polarity of the diode would just be based on the incoming power polarity.

Comment: I mean you're putting a diode on the circuit board, is the way the user/installer wiring it up guaranteed? Maybe you're not even putting it on board, I have no idea.

Comment: you could use a resistor instead of a diode, although it will dissipate power when the relay is engaged - the big issue here is that not only do you want DC and AC, you also want different voltages, which adds complication. How are you going to switch them on and off?

Comment: I'm thinking that I might use a DPDT switch that has an AC and DC setting which changes the protection circuit depending on which type of valve I am using. That way I don't need a one size fits all solution.

Answer (score 1):

> *my question is when I use the same circuit for an AC valve, will the
> diode provided any use or could it potentially cause problems?*

Hint: think about what would happen if you connected a diode across an AC supply. Another hint: how much current will flow when the diode is forward biased in one half of the AC's waveform.

You should design a snubber circuit (capable of running on AC and DC) and, make sure that it suppresses flyback voltages sufficiently for the switch ratings used for activating the solenoid.

Comment: My first instinct says I would be shorting out half of the waveform. Which I think would be bad without a resistor in series with the diode to dissipate this short. But that'd waste a lot of energy and generate a lot of heat right?

Comment: Exactly @AustinFox